# npm install return different vulnerabilities how to solve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm, npm-install

I post one of the errors that pop out while I use npm audit for the details. Any solution?

```
Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in firebase - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-fpm5-vv97-jfwg
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install fcm-node@1.3.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/fcm-notification/node_modules/@firebase/util
  @firebase/app  <=0.6.13-longpoll.66863f547 || 0.6.14-2021026232412 - 0.6.14-canary.fd16bb26d || 0.6.15-2021119233939 - 0.6.15-eap-storage-emulator.ed256f582
  Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/util
  node_modules/fcm-notification/node_modules/@firebase/app
    firebase-admin  4.0.0 - 11.4.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/app
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/database
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @google-cloud/firestore
    Depends on vulnerable versions of dicer
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jsonwebtoken
    Depends on vulnerable versions of node-forge
    node_modules/fcm-node/node_modules/firebase-admin
    node_modules/fcm-notification/node_modules/firebase-admin
      fcm-node  >=1.4.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of firebase-admin
      node_modules/fcm-node
      fcm-notification  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of firebase-admin
      node_modules/fcm-notification
  @firebase/database  <=0.7.1-canary.fc9de467b || 0.8.0-202010180421 - 0.8.0-canary.bab4e1935 || 0.8.1-1.0.0-eap-firestore-debug.9c6096f43 - 0.8.1-canary.ff9dc3460 || 0.8.2-20210721223 - 0.8.2-longpoll.66863f547 || 0.8.3-2021012224526 - 0.8.3-canary.fb90580e5 || 0.9.0-2021019222814 - 0.9.0-canary.d9b945fed || 0.9.1-2021026232412 - 0.9.1-canary.fd16bb26d || 0.9.2-202112213818 - 0.9.2-canary.f5139220e || 0.9.3-202119234540 - 0.9.3-canary.ee6980dee || 0.9.4-2021119233939 - 0.9.4-eap-storage-emulator.ed256f582
  Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/util
  node_modules/fcm-notification/node_modules/@firebase/database
```

I tried to use npm install and npm install firebase --save but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

if its not working try this two:

```
npm uninstall fcm-node firebase-admin
npm install fcm-node@1.3.0 firebase-admin@9.11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you  can try
npm audit fix --force
hope it will solve your problem